# The architecture of the task processing system by interval

Tags: postgresql, go, database-design, architecture, rabbitmq

We have a large list of sites and commands that need to be executed on this site at a given interval in our database.

Table:
ID, SITE, COMMANDS (json: command_name => interval minutes)

`1, example1.ru, { "command_name1": 5, "command_name2": 5, "command_name3": 60}`

There is also a console application that can perform various tasks on the site.
For example:

- Check response status
- Checking HTTPS certificates
- Search for some data in the content
- etc.

Our need to design Golang application in such a way that it can be easily scaled (i.e. create multiple instances of the application on different machines).

I would like to understand how best to organize the architecture? A table in a database is an example of a structure. Perhaps it needs to be organized differently, for more efficient use.

Please help with the design, and describe what and how to organize.

Sorry for bad English.

I see this option:

1. I connect rabbitmq - it will act as a task queue for execution.
2. Golang will work:

   1. The consumer, which listens to the task queue, takes the task and gives it to internal workers (goroutines) for execution. After execution, the date of the last execution will be marked in the database.
   2. A separate goroutine that scans the database once a minute, looks for tasks that have not been completed and puts them in a queue for execution. A note is created in the database that the task has been taken away for execution (i.e., the task is being locked).

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions can be workout using Kafka. Suppose you have written a service that is consuming messages from the Kafka Topic, on which producers are writing tasks to be processed, so If you launch say 3 consumers, within the consumer group (say `processing-gp`), then In Kafka it is by design a single consumer inter alia will pick the task and process it. kafka is easily scalable along with a number of partitions.